# python Catched exception still raise up

Tags: python, exception

This is my first time asking question on stackoverflow.Sorry about my poor English,English is not my mother language.

I wrote a try/except clause like this:

```
try:
    hostname = result["hostname"]
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
    return {"retcode":1,"description":e}
```

When there is no "hostname" key in result, it will occur a KeyError exception.When I ran my code,I saw the exception had been catched,because logger.error(e) lay a log in my log file.But it still raised a exception, didn't return this {"retcode":1,"description":"failed"}.

The exception information is like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/claire/myflask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",              line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/claire/myflask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/claire/myflask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 484, in wrapper
  return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
  File "/home/claire/myflask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 513, in make_response
  resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/claire/myflask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/representations/json.py", line 21, in output_json
  dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
  return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
  chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
  raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
  TypeError: KeyError('hostname',) is not JSON serializable
```

I'm using Python 3.5.2 and Flask 0.12.2 and Flask-RESTful 0.3.6 .
This code is in a flask restful API.
The full code is like this:

itf.py

```
import json
import requests
import time
import os,sys,re
import subprocess
import docker

def dosomething():
    do something.....
    return result    //result is a json.
```

api.py

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from .mylogger import logger
from itf import dosomething

class TheRestAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, param):
        result = dosomething(param)

        try:
            hostname = result["hostname"]
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            return {"retcode":1,"description":e}

        do other things .....
        return {"retcode":0,"description":"success"}
```

When I use a get request invoke this restAPI, I get this respond:

```
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
```

I don't know why it execute to "logger.error(e)" here ,but don't return the next statement, and why I use  "except Exception as e " can't catch the KeyError exception.

Then I tried this:

```
try:
    hostname = result["hostname"]
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
    logger.error(str(type(e)))
    return {"retcode":1,"description":"failed"}
except KeyError as e:
    logger.info("second except.......")
    return {"retcode":1,"description":"failed"}
except TypeError as e:
    logger.info("third except.......")
    return {"retcode":1,"description":"failed"}
```

Still can't catch The KeyError exception.

This is my logger module:

```
import sys
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


LOG_PATH_FILE = '%s/app/agent.log'%sys.path[0]
LOG_MODE = 'a'
LOG_MAX_SIZE = 1*1024*1024 # 1M per file
LOG_MAX_FILES = 4
LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-10s[%(filename)s:%(lineno)d(%(funcName)s)] %(message)s"

handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_PATH_FILE, LOG_MODE, LOG_MAX_SIZE, LOG_MAX_FILES)
formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: The error isn't happening in the code with the try/except.

Comment: This exception only occured when there is no "hostname" key in result. If result have this key in it , it wouldn't occur exception. I tried this.

Comment: Fine, but that doesn't change the fact that the error is not happening in the code where you access the result.

Comment: Is there any way I can catch it or I can find where it happened.

Comment: Somewhere (most likely in _dosomething()_ or _do other things..._) you're trying to access the key `('hostname',)` which is a__tuple__ containing the string _"hostname"_, you get a `KeyError` which when trying to be converted to _json_ generates the above `TypeError`. Note: the last 2 `except` clauses from the "before last" (at this point) snippet will never going to be hit because of the 1st one.

Comment: Thank you. I found where the exception happened. It happened on this line `return {"retcode":1,"description":e}`, when convert e to a part of json.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a KeyError but a TypeError in the traceback.

Don't you have a custom logger.error function? or custom formater?

The error is from this line imho

Comment: Yes , I have a custom log module ,that is why I import a logger object, it used for lay logs in my custom format.You mean the exception happened in the logger module.

Comment: I uploaded the logger module code to the question content.

Comment: I deleted `logger.error(e)` this line, still raised the exception. Maybe the exception is not happened in logger module.

Comment: Thank you. I found where the exception happened. It happened on this line:`return {"retcode":1,"description":"failed"}`,actually, in my code ,this line is `return {"retcode":1,"description":e}`, the exception happened when convert "e" this variable into a json.

Comment: hehe, you did not say us everything from beginning. You're welcome

Comment: Sorry,I didn't realize that is a bug there.I was try to explain my situation simply.I will note this next time.Your advice did help me found the problem, thanks.